# Dropping connection on geometry_msgs::Transform

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting an error

```
[ERROR] [1357761577.273746553]: Client [/gazebo] wants topic /base_controller/command to have datatype/md5sum [geometry_msgs/Twist/9f195f881246fdfa2798d1d3eebca84a], but our version has [geometry_msgs/Transform/ac9eff44abf714214112b05d54a3cf9b]. Dropping connection.
```

when I initialize

```
vel_pub_ = n_.advertise<geometry_msgs::Transform>("cmd_vel", 1);
```

but if I do it

```
vel_pub_ =n_.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1);
```

it works fine ...
why cant I do Transform

NOTE: I am trying to work on Pr2 simulator Gazebo..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51817/dropping-connection-on-geometry_msgs::transform/) by [zeroth](https://answers.ros.org/users/3656/zeroth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason it crashes is simply because the topic you are publishing to is expecting a message of type `geometry_msgs::Twist`. So, that's the one to send. Simple as that!

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2